# Problems receiving images from MRI console

Tags: jboss, dcm4che

I have integrated dcm4chee-2.18.3-mysql with X-RAY, CT Scan and MRI machine. From X-RAY and CT Scan machine .dcm images are received in my dcm4chee-2.18.3-mysql but to access images from MRI finding issues while receiving images.

```
09:36:32,284 INFO  [FsmImpl] received AAssociateRQ
        appCtxName:     1.2.840.10008.3.1.1.1/DICOM Application Context Name
        implClass:      1.3.46.670589.11.0.0.51.4.53.1
        implVersion:    Philips MR 53.1
        calledAET:      DCM4CHEE_SCP
        callingAET:     INGENIA
        maxPDULen:      32768
        asyncOpsWindow:
        pc-1:   as=1.2.840.10008.1.1/Verification SOP Class
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.70/JPEG Lossless, Non- Hierarchical, Firs
t-Order Prediction (Process 14 [Selection Value 1])
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.90/JPEG 2000 Lossless Image Compression
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1/Explicit VR Little Endian
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.2/Explicit VR Big Endian
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
        pc-3:   as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.2/CT Image Storage
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.70/JPEG Lossless, Non- Hierarchical, Firs
t-Order Prediction (Process 14 [Selection Value 1])
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.90/JPEG 2000 Lossless Image Compression
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1/Explicit VR Little Endian
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.2/Explicit VR Big Endian
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2/Implicit VR Little Endian
        pc-5:   as=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.4/MR Image Storage
                ts=1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.70/JPEG Lossless, Non- Hierarchical, Firs
```